# Trouble while adding list to quick launch

Tags: 2010, quick-launch

I am creating the document library in the code behind, I want to display that library in the quick launch.

My code is:

```
bool flag=true;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMsg.Visible = false;
    txtDocumentLibrary.Focus();
    btnDocumentLibrary.Click += new EventHandler(btnDocumentLibrary_Click);
}

void btnDocumentLibrary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDocumentLibrary.Text))
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Please Enter Name";
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMsg.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {             
          using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
          {
              using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
              {
                  // Chck if library name already exists...
                  foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                  {
                      if (list.Title.ToUpper().Equals(txtDocumentLibrary.Text.ToUpper()))
                      {
                           flag = false;
                           break;
                      }
                  }
                  if (flag)
                  {
                      web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                      Guid id = web.Lists.Add(txtDocumentLibrary.Text.Trim(), "Created Programmatically", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                       web.Update();
                       lblMsg.Text = txtDocumentLibrary.Text.Trim() + " Library Created Successfully";
                       lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                       lblMsg.Visible = true;
                       SPList lst = web.Lists[id];
                       lst.OnQuickLaunch = true;
                       lst.Update();
                       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       lblMsg.Text = "Library Name Already Exists Please Enter Another";
                       lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                       lblMsg.Visible = true;
                   }
               }
           }                     
     }
}
```

Everything works well but my problem is that the quick launch affects after the page is reloaded. i.e. if I want to see newly created library, I have to refresh the page. I want to update the quick launch the moment when the library is created.

How should I tackle this error?

Answer (score 0):

users1100,

In this situation where everything works right, I would probably just write in some code to perform the refresh for the user. I found a good source while searching this on the internet. Just create the method and call it after all of your other code has been executed.

**Disclaimer**: I have NOT tried this solution myself yet.

```
protected void ReloadPage()
{
 string script =
  @"<script language='JavaScript'>
  location.href=document.openlocation.href.value
  </script>";
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), string.Empty, script, false);
}
```

The link to the site that explains this is at http://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/reload-page-from-code-behind/